# Excel VBA Delete Row based on column value

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to write a Excel Macro that goes though K1--->K(lastrow) and looks for the value "OptedOut", and if it finds that value then it deletes that row. I appreciate the help guys. The only part that is wrong is the For Each C part, because I don't understand arrays, and possibly "c.Value = "OptedOut" Then Rows(c).Delete" kinda pulled that out of my ass.

Thanks all!

```
Sub DuplicateDelete()
Sheets("ALL CLIENTS").Range("A1:J10000").Copy Destination:=Sheets("ClientsAndEmailsThatAreOK").Range("A1:J10000")

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox LastRow
End With


'Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range(Range(Cells("K1"), Cells(LastRow, "K")))
    If c.Value = "OptedOut" Then Rows(c).Delete
Next c


End Sub
```

Comment: Is this code suppose to wrok with sheet "ALL CLIENTS" or "ClientsAndEmailsThatAreOK" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop backwards when deleting rows (or other objects).

Also, instead of using `ActiveSheet` try to fully qualify your `Worksheet` object, such as `Sheets("ClientsAndEmailsThatAreOK")`.

Try the code below, explanation inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DuplicateDelete()

Dim C As Range
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

Sheets("ALL CLIENTS").Range("A1:J10000").Copy Destination:=Sheets("ClientsAndEmailsThatAreOK").Range("A1:J10000")

' I'm assuming you want to work with sheet "ClientsAndEmailsThatAreOK" (if not then switch it)
With Sheets("ClientsAndEmailsThatAreOK")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox LastRow

    ' always loop backwards when deleting rows
    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If .Range("K" & i).Value2 = "OptedOut" Then .Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```